# Additional keyrings for APT in trusted.gpg.d

Tags: apt, repository

I'm creating a package that will automatically install some repositories to all hosts in the LAN. The package will be accessible from the central repository.

I've discovered that repo lists can be dropped in '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list'. Now I need to import their keys, for instance, [this one](http://deb.opera.com/archive.key). However, when I drop it into '/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/Opera.gpg', `apt-get update` gives me a plenty of `NO_PUBKEY` errors for **all** repos I have, including Opera!

What's wrong? :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Keys downloaded from repositories should be joint into a new GPG keyring so you can drop them into '/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/*.gpg', like this:

```
gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring ./Opera.gpg --import Opera.key
sudo cp Opera.gpg /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/Opera.gpg
```

Comment: Doesn't work, neither with version gpg 1.4.x nor 2.1:  `gpg: keyblock resource './Opera.gpg': file open error` and `gpg: no writable keyring found: eof`.  To make it work, you need to **do first: `touch Opera.gpg`**

Comment: I think this answer is completely misleading or at least outdated. The current ubuntu does not support `GPG keybox database` file format as keyring fragment. The file generated by command suggested in this answer actually generate the keybox database instead of key file.

Answer (score 17):

You can actually get the best of both worlds: create an additional keyring in `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/` and use `apt-key` instead of `gpg` directly.

If you already have a keyfile locally, such as `Opera.key`, then run the following command:

```
sudo apt-key --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/Opera.gpg add Opera.key
```

Of course, you can still import the key directly as MestreLion demonstrated:

```
wget -q -O - http://deb.opera.com/archive.key | sudo apt-key --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/Opera.gpg add -
```

Comment: Note that specifying the keyring `Opera.gpg` will create the keyring in the current directory, not `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d`. Therefore make sure to either specify the full path, or to move the newly created keyring to the `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d` directory (apt version 1.2.27).

Comment: For people looking to import keys from a key server, I found this command useful: `apt-key --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/keyring-name.gpg adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv GPGKEYID`

Comment: `apt-key` is deprecated: see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1286545/what-commands-exactly-should-replace-the-deprecated-apt-key/1307181#1307181

Answer (score 2):

Additionally, you could use `apt-key` to add the key for you in instead of manually dropping a file to that path. Assuming you saved the file as `Opera.key`:

```
sudo apt-key add Opera.key
```

You could even download and import the key file on-the-fly, instead of saving it to a local file:

```
wget -q -O - http://deb.opera.com/archive.key | sudo apt-key add -
```

Apt-key manages the contents of `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg` main file instead of using the directory, which may be a convenience or a burden for you.

Comment: apt-key is deprecated for long time already and eventually this is go away after ubuntu 22.04

Comment: @Wang: true, but consider my answer is almost 10 years old, way before `apt-key` was deprecated. Currently I use `apt-manage` from [repolib](https://repolib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), which does the proper thing: add the key to `/etc/apt/keyrings` and pin it to a particular repository

Answer (score -1):

I think the accepted answer is completely misleading or at least outdated. The current ubuntu does not support GPG keybox database file format as keyring fragment.

If you use that answer the apt update will raise warning: `W: The key(s) in the keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/test.gpg are ignored as the file has an unsupported filetype.`

The rest answers involve deprecated command `apt-key` which does not exist anymore in current ubuntu release.

The correct way to do this is

```
# cd into a dir which is 700 for yourself
gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring tmp.keyring.gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys <key-id1> <key-id2>
gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring tmp.keyring.gpg --output my-keys.gpg --export
sudo cp /tmp/my-keys.gpg /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/
```

And please noticed the new apt support armoured key file so if you already have the .asc file you do NOT need to dearmor it as old ubuntu (<16.04)

Comment: True, any answer suggesting `apt-key`, including mine, is deprecated in 2023. But so is manually adding globally-trusted keys to `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/`, as that was the main reason for deprecating `apt-key`! This is better explained in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1307181/11015), and a good solution is described in [this one](https://askubuntu.com/a/1412554/11015)

Comment: unfortunately @MestreLion your suggestion is not good. It depends on 3rd party tool apt-manage

Comment: You can always do it manually, as described in my first link. That answer, among [many others](https://askubuntu.com/q/1286545/11015), have detailed steps on how to pin a downloaded key to a specific repository. `apt-manage` is just a convenience. Suggesting `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/` is no better than using `apt-key`: you might not be using a deprecated tool, but you're simply manually doing the same deprecated approach.