# What commands (exactly) should replace the deprecated apt-key?

Tags: apt, repository, keyrings

Setting up keys for a local repository on a new ubuntu 20.10 virtual machine, I got a message that apt-key add was deprecated and I should read the `apt-key`(8) man page. The `apt-key`(8) man page is a collection of words strung together, but if it contains information I can't winkle it out. Can anyone tell me what, exactly, I should type on my terminal instead of:

```
apt-key add name-of-file
```

The command does apparently still work after honking at me, so I was able to proceed, but would like to know what I'll need to do in the future.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I stumbled on the same problem and luckily some other question lighted the way.
In my example I was trying to add a teamviewer repository to a recent Kali linux and I was being blocked by the key verification.

I'm quite sure there's a more elegant way to do this but the following steps helped me fix the problem:

1. Download the relevant key

   `wget -O - https://download.teamviewer.com/download/linux/signature/TeamViewer2017.asc > ~/teamviewer.key`
2. Verify the type of file

   `file ~/teamviewer.key`

   it should be *PGP public key block Public-Key (old)*
3. Create a keyring

   `gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring ./teamviewer_keyring.gpg --import teamviewer.key`
4. This file is still not a valid key that can be added to */etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/* since it's a keyring, but from the keyring we can extract the key with

   `gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring ./teamviewer_keyring.gpg --export > ./teamviewer.gpg`
5. This file is the key you want to move to the trusted key folder

   `sudo mv ./teamviewer.gpg /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/`

happy `sudo apt update`!!!

Comment: Do not use this accepted answer and do not put files in `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/`. See the aswer with the most upvotes for a better solution.

Answer (score 287):

#### You need to know *why* `apt-key add` is deprecated

All of the answers so far work around the *symptom* ("Don't use `apt-key add`") but fail to address the *actual problem* that led to `apt-key add` being deprecated. The problem is not a question of appending a key to one big keyring file `etc/apt/trusted.gpg` vs manually putting single-key keyring files into the directory `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/`. These two things are equivalent, and doing either one is a huge security risk.

The problem is that any key you add to **either** of the above is completely and unconditionally trusted by apt. This means that when installing any package from any repo (including the official distro repos), apt will happily accept the package being signed by **any** of those trusted keys (whether the key belongs to the repository the package is coming from or not). This weakens the assurance provided by the package signing mechanism against malicous packages being injected into the official Ubuntu mirrors network.

What we want to do instead is configure apt to accept signatures from a third-party repository only on packages being installed from that repository — no cross-signing. Apt's default pinning rules give higher priority to official distro repos, which (in conjunction with proper key management) offers some protection against third-party repos replacing distro-provided packages. (At least, I *think* that's default. You can use `apt-cache policy` to inspect the current pin priorities, and if needed you can adjust pinning based on `origin` to achieve this effect. See `man apt_preferences` for details.)

The instructions given in Ugo Delle Donne's answer for converting the key to the (legacy) keyring v4 format that apt will accept are correct and helpful, but that's only half of the solution. I'll reiterate them here (cleaned up slightly) so all the steps are consolidated in one place:

- Download the key:

  - `wget https://host.domain.tld/path/to/<keyfile>.<ext>` 
    (No need for `-O` or `>`; `wget` defaults to saving the file in your current directory with the same filename it has on the server.)
- Verify that the filetype is "PGP public key block Public-Key (old)":

  - `file <keyfile>.<ext>`
- `gpg` supports a number of key formats, so if your key is in a different format, convert it by importing it into a temp keyring, then exporting it again:

  - `gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring ./temp-keyring.gpg --import <keyfile>.<ext>`
  - `gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring ./temp-keyring.gpg --export --output <your-keyfile-name>.gpg`
  - `rm temp-keyring.gpg`

Now that you have your converted key, **do not** add it to `apt`'s trusted keystore by copying it into `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/`. Instead, put it somewhere like `/etc/apt/keyrings/`. (You might need to create that `keyrings` directory first.) There's nothing special about that location, it's just a convention recommended by `man 5 sources.list` in Ubuntu 22.04 and a related [Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianRepository/UseThirdParty) entry.

At this point, nothing has changed and `apt` doesn't know the key exists. The last step is to modify the specific `.list` file for the repository to tell apt where to find the key for *that specific repo*.

- Edit the file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/<example>.list`, and in between `deb` and the url, add `[signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/<your-keyfile-name>.gpg]`

Now apt will accept that key's signature for all packages in that repo and *only* that repo.

**Notes:**

- If you already have keyring files in `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/`, you can <strike>copy</strike> **move** them to `/etc/apt/keyrings/` as-is, and then update all the corresponding `.list` files so each one has a `signed-by` field pointing to its own key.
- If you already have keys in the `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg` keyring file beyond the official repo keys, [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/605017/1112594) details the steps to locate and remove them. You can then follow all the same steps above to set them up the safer way. (Exporting them from that keyring is also possible, but the exact steps are left as an exercise for the reader.)
- To import a repo's key *from a keyserver* to a standalone file:

  - `gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring <output-file-name>.gpg --keyserver <some.keyserver.uri> --recv-keys <fingerprint>`
  - This should give you a key that apt will accept without conversion.
- Apt is still very trusting, and a malicious or compromised repo can bypass this measure easily because packages currently can run arbitrary shell code as root in their setup scripts. Closing off one attack vector doesn't hurt, though, and progress is (slowly) being made on other fronts.
- Optionally, you can switch to the newer, more verbose `Deb822` format using individual `.sources` files instead of `.list` files. It's more work, but personally I find the result far more readable.

**Sources:**

- [Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianRepository/UseThirdParty)
- [Excellent and detailed answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/332672/how-to-add-a-third-party-repo-and-key-in-debian/582853#582853) on Unix&Linux StackExchange

Comment: No need to import/export the key for conversion. You can dearmor the key in one step using `wget -O - https://host.domain.tld/path/to/<keyfile>.<ext> | gpg --dearmor > /usr/local/share/keyrings/<your-keyfile-name>.gpg`

Comment: @Hrobky yes, **if** the key is an old binary-format "public key block" that has been ascii-armored, that will work. However, if the key file is in the newer binary "keybox database" format, which apt doesn't support, it needs to be *actually converted* to the old public key block format (after dearmoring if applicable). If there's a one-step command for that binary→binary conversion, I haven't encountered it yet.

Comment: Great answer. @Askeli could you give an example of a key for which the direct `gpg --dearmor` works, and one for which it doesn't?
Eg am I correct that [this mopidy key](https://apt.mopidy.com/mopidy.gpg) would work with `--dearmor`, but [this google key](https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg) wouldn't? Note passing google key directly to `gpg --dearmor` still exits with error code 0, which suggests... it works?

Comment: For what it's worth I haven't come up against any key that didn't work with @Hrobky's recommendation of piping it through `gpg --dearmor`

Comment: @laur I'm afraid I don't have examples. I downloaded, converted, and installed a bunch of keys right around when I wrote this answer, and I'm pretty sure I remember encountering at least one that apt didn't recognize even after `--dearmor`, which sent me looking for the conversion method in my answer… but I didn't make note of which ones. As a general rule, I'd say there's no harm in piping through `--dearmor` by default (if the key's not ascii-armored, gpg will exit successfully without changing anything). If apt chokes on the resulting key, *then* try the binary→binary conversion workaround.

Comment: "This means that any third-party repo whose apt signing key is in there is allowed to replace any package on your entire system, no questions asked." -- this is possible even if you use the newer method, no? Because apt will still have no concept of which repository is permitted to ship which packages. Unless you also implement some pinning, but I don't see that in any instructions.

Comment: @laur An (ASCII-)armored PGP key is just a base64-encoded version of the non-armored PGP key file, with some header/footer text to indicate it's a PGP key. This is done so that the data can be easily sent using methods which only accept/expect ASCII text, and not arbitrary binary data. Convention is to use the `.asc` extension for such files, and `.gpg` for binary key files. Mopidy apparently isn't following that convention. It seems that `file` will always report "PGP public key block Public-Key (old)" for an armored file, and something more detailed for an unarmored file.

Comment: @laur When in doubt, open the file in a text editor (e.g. `less my-file.ext`, press Q to exit), and if it's armored, it will have human-readable headers like "BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK". If it's a binary file, `less` will tell you this before opening it, as trying to display its content will render gibberish/[mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake).

Comment: Is there a reason why this process is not automatic with some `apt` command to replace the deprecated behavior? By the description it seems it can easily be scripted.

Comment: On Ubuntu 21.04, I have Ubuntu keys in `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/` directory, like `ubuntu-keyring-2012-cdimage.gpg` and `ubuntu-keyring-2018-archive.gpg`. And these do not have corresponding `.list` files. So I guess not everything in that directory should be moved blindly.

Comment: Does it protect against a third-party repo being able to replace any package in the system? If yes, how?

Comment: It appears to me that ppa's will now also be a problem? `add-apt-repository ppa:user/ppa-name` will add a file to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` as well as the corresponding key to `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d`. Should PPA's get the same treatment?

Comment: You can combine this answer with [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1398346) to export existing keys in the default trusted keyring and move them into your local directory too (even on Debian some keys will be in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` while some will be in `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg`. You could also mention that the `signed-by` can come after `arch=amd64` following a space.  It might seem obvious but some people (guilty) might want that confirmation - just for completeness of your answer!  Great answer otherwise!

Comment: @RobieBasak It looks like Debian does have [instructions for this](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianRepository/UseThirdParty#Complete_example), but I have to say that this sounds _really_ complicated.  Hopefully `add-apt-repository` will be updated or some other tool will be put together to automate this process...

Comment: According to "man 5 sources.list" on Ubuntu 22.04, if you are a system manager who wants to add an apt source with a keyring, the keyring should go to /etc/apt/keyrings/ (e.g. for the winehq repo). On the other hand, if you are a pkg maintainer who wants to install a keyring with the package postinst script (e.g. google-chrome, Microsoft teams, slack) you should place it in /usr/share/keyrings/.

Comment: Try to imagine you have 10 seconds to communicate whatever you said and the other person then has 1 minute to execute it else we all perish. That is what security should look like. Not some sprawling thing with huge room for errors and breaches.

Comment: Well, i'm not going to be doing any of that until it's made less involved since even LLVM still uses apt-key. I am more likely to pipe the output of apt through sed to strip the warning then go through all this for every key.

Comment: Thank you. This is the only answer on the whole web that actually outlines the correct way of handling signed repositories on the latest apt. Nothing else is remotely relevant. For the simple answer, put they key for your repo somewhere logical like /usr/share/keyrings, and reference that directly in the /etc/apt/sources.list or sources.list.d line for the repo. Simple as that. Just point it directly at the right key.

Comment: Any you’re **completely missing the point**! Ask yourself: *Does the stuff you recommend fit what Ubuntu exists for?* …No, it absolutely doesn’t The correct way would be, for the package manager tool of your choice to ask the user: “*Do you want to completely and unconditionally trust $packageSourcePeople? with your computer?*” … And it must ask that too, when installing Ubuntu in the first place! Because you are acting like Ubuntu maintainers are somehow magically unquestionably impossible to corrupt, and any different from those other people. **That is provably dangerously false.**

Comment: Also, asking people to magically manually find the damn key, when there is no way/command to determine it from the ppa URI, is just insulting at this point, and you can just go: “WE ARE THE BORG^WAPPLE! RELINQUISH YOUR OWN FREE WILL! RESISTANCE IS FUTILE! OBEY! OBEY! IÄ! IÄ! CANONICAL FHTAGN!” 

Comment: Also, `apt-add-repository` still uses `apt-key add`! Which is the origin on the entire problem in the first placce! And you did not even address it with even one word.

Comment: If there is already another entry between deb and URL, like `[arch=amd64]` you must add it inside the brackets instead, like `deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/vivaldi-release.gpg] http://repo.vivaldi.com/stable/deb/ stable main` otherwise you get syntax error from apt: `Malformed entry 3 in list file`.

Comment: Please add @IngoSteinke's suggestion to your answer (how to add signed-by if there is already a bracketed entry). Also, the most annoying part of this workflow is finding the gpg key for each source, because there's no consistent way they are stored. I ended up just removing all keys from my system and then iteratively running apt-key update and googling each problem source to find its key. I was surprised how many ancient keys were on here, probably good to have removed them...

Answer (score 13):

The reason for this deprecation is because using `apt-key add` simply appends the gpg key to the trusted global APT keyring. It's similar to the preferred method of adding `local_repo.list` to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` instead of using `add-apt-repository dep /link/to/repo version`, which appends the message to the global `sources.list` file.

I think it's a bit more awkward to understand than using the .d folder, but essentially we want to get the gpg key into a standalone keyring file, then point to this keyring file in the source listing. The default keyring file location is `/usr/share/keyrings`, and it can be a .asc or .gpg file. I'm not sure the difference but I do know the global keyring files are binary files, not plaintext.

### For example:

Using generic names can be a bit hard to understand sometimes, so here is an example of installing mongoDB:

Get the MongoDB gpg key and add it to a new keyring file

```
curl https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-4.2.asc | sudo tee -a /usr/share/keyrings/buster-mongodb-org-4_2.asc
```

Add a source entry for apt, pointed to this new keyring.

For example, if your repository file is located at `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4_2.list` run the following command to add the keyfile:

```
echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/buster-mongodb-org-4_2.asc] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian buster/mongodb-org/4.2 main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4_2.list
```

Install mongodb from this newly added repo

`sudo apt install -y mongodb-org`

### Reference

This is still new to me, but most of what I know came from [this excellent answer in the unix SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/463140/448279)

Comment: I'm curious how the file `server-4.2.asc` from the remote server turned into `buster-mongodb-org-4_2.asc` on the local side. Is that name important somehow?

Comment: It should be noted that newer versions of mongodb may also require `[ arch=amd64,arm64 ]` on Ubuntu and I'm not sure yet what the separator is to add that along with the key path.

Comment: @mchid The separator between options is a space, like this: `[arch=amd64,arm64 signed-by=...]`

Answer (score 9):

I created a shell script that can download and install keys to be used with `[signed-by=]` declaration in `sources.list`.

It's available on [github.com/ameinild/add-apt-key](https://github.com/ameinild/add-apt-key).

> ## POSIX Script for installing APT keys
>
> ### General help
>
> This script will help with installing PGP keys for APT repositories.
>
> This script supports up to 2 arguments:
>
> - 1st argument is input file. This can be either:
>
>   - An URL - key will be downloaded into current path (using wget or curl)
>   - A filename - reads an existing key in current path
>   - A path and a filename - reads an existing key in given path
> - 2nd argument is key output path and output name. This can be either:
>
>   - Only filename - output path is set in config, saved as given filename
>   - A path and a filename - output path is given here, saved as given filename
>   - Only a path (end with /) - output path is given here, filename is taken from existing key
>   - Empty - output path is set in config, filename is taken from existing key
>
> This script has a config file `/usr/local/etc/add-apt-key.conf`, where the
> following variables can be set:
>
> - `keypath`   : path to store converted key - default is `/etc/apt/keyrings`
> - `verbosity` : if set to Yes - displays extra output
> - `removetmp` : if set to Yes - remove input (non-converted) file
>
> Example 1: (`PWD=/root`)
>
> ```
> sudo add-apt-key https://mariadb.org/mariadb_release_signing_key.asc /usr/share/keyrings/
> ```
>
> Will download key in `/root`, convert it and store as
> `/usr/share/keyrings/mariadb_release_signing_key.gpg`
>
> Example 2: (`PWD=/home/user`)
>
> ```
> sudo add-apt-key /root/mariadb_release_signing_key.asc /usr/share/keyrings/mariadbkey
> ```
>
> Will use existing key in `/root`, convert it and store as
> `/usr/share/keyrings/mariadbkey.gpg`
>
> Example 3: (`PWD=/home/user`)
>
> ```
> sudo add-apt-key mariadb_release_signing_key.asc mariadbkey
> ```
>
> Will use existing key in `/home/user`, convert it and store as
> `/etc/apt/keyrings/mariadbkey.gpg`
>
> After installing the PGP key, it is also possible to add the key and repository to `/etc/apt/sources.list`
>
> - The choice to add this will be presented in the script as the first input option
> - If Yes is chosen, the repository string must be pasted as the second input option
>
> This completes the key installation by adding the corresponding repository line to `/etc/apt/sources.list`
>
> ### Installation
>
> Install by running the following commands:
>
> ```
> sudo curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ameinild/add-apt-key/master/add-apt-key -o /usr/local/bin/add-apt-key
> sudo curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ameinild/add-apt-key/master/add-apt-key.conf -o /usr/local/etc/add-apt-key.conf
> sudo chmod a+rx /usr/local/bin/add-apt-key
> ```

Comment: Therefore, it is clearly demonstrated above that Linux is definitely not adapted to average end-users. Those Ubuntu and others should warned that you need serious advanced skills and have to be willing to spend a lot of time training, searching, and dealing , with those issues... even-more, with small guarantee  that you that whatever you do will work or not create further problems. That's  dishonesty.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that future versions of Ubuntu will have adapted its own scripts to the "new" way of installing PGP keys. In the meantime, I've written a script to help other users achieve the closest possible to automating this. If you find it too advanced and not useful that's OK, but it was actually meant as a help.

Comment: The script is updated with an option to write GPG key and repository directly to `/etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: @YannMonnier you are 100% right. If the Ubuntu developers cannot match their "security concerns" with what the community actually needs, the Ubuntu desktop will just stop being a viable option. I'm a big fan of Slackware, where the tools are much more streamlined and simple (although documentation is lacking).  They are also likely "less secure", but we're not running a bank here - it's a PC!

Comment: New default location for keys is `/etc/apt/keyrings`.

Comment: @levitopher How is Slackware a viable option with like 2,000 packages available compared to 100,000 available for Ubuntu? And here we are on a question about adding a PPA to easily expand that number well beyond 100,000.

Comment: @mchid: The tradeoff is less pre-packaged software for a much more functional and stable OS. After the first 2000 packages, you get much less reliability. Combined with this nonesense with the apt keys...you can always compile from source, it's just an attitude about dialing in "convenience" with "quality" - Slackware leans on quality, Ubuntu on convenience.

My point above was really about the illusion of Ubuntu being "easy to use". In a small slice of the market, that's true, but for many, it's just a lie.

Comment: @mchid my script reference the keys directly for each repo.

Comment: ...I love how this comment section just continues to argue (all on it's own, without my direction) for Slackware being a better option then Ubuntu (not even...I only need "viable"!). Old methods that aren't recommended anymore? Nice long term planning. Multiple links to give you multiple depths of understanding? Not exactly KISS. Additional steps for keyservers vs "websites"? Come on Google don't fail me now!

It's possible Slackware is only viable because it's a smaller project, but still - the focus on reliability and long-term planning avoids most of the nonesense in this thread.

Comment: @mchid: I think you are missing the point of KISS (or at least, the interpretation of it I'm suggesting is applicable here). It's not "blindly push a button and go into space - simple". It's "make every button you push to go into space easily understandable and fixable - simple". I'm suggesting the structure Ubuntu has constructed around their software delivery system is more like the black box example - easy to use, but when something's broken it requires an entirely different set of skills to get it going again. On Slackware, the set of skills required to install and fix is the same.

Comment: Thank you for writing this script @ArturMeinild. Seems very useful, but it does also demonstrate that Linux is far too complicated for casual use as a normal operating system. All we're trying to do is install an app, something that should not even require technical skills, and instead we need OS experts like you to write scripts and lengthy explanations just so that programmers and system admins can figure out how to install an app.

Comment: Check out `apt-manage` from my [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1412554/720005), I think that's the way to move forward.

Comment: @Lockszmith but will it be ported to Ubuntu? Right now it seems it's only for Pop_OS!

Comment: I've edited my answer for clarity, installation on Ubuntu (I do it on Ubuntu 20.04 and all following versions) has been simple enough, and the results is a 'clean' system.

Answer (score 7):

As a direct workalike, replace `apt-key add` with `gpg --dearmor`:

`curl [KEYURL] | sudo gpg --dearmor --yes -o /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/[KEYFILE].gpg`

However, this is not recommended (other than as a workalike to apt-key) since all keys in the trusted directory are unconditionally trusted; it is better to put the output in a (non-globally) trusted directory (as others have suggested), and have each source specify which key(s) to trust, individually.

Answer (score 7):

UPDATE: 2023-Nov-15, Back in August, a PR I submitted to the apt-manage project was accepted, it includes a quick-install script which will install apt-manage on Debian and Ubuntu and their derivitives.

Once again, I've modified my answer below, replacing the installation with the quick-install script.

---

UPDATE: 2023-May-16, I can confirm apt-manage is the safest most consistent way I found to manage apt sources with keys properly.

<s>I've rewritten the answer, removing my personal script (you can view it in the [revisions history](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1412554/revisions) if you'd like) to focus on the command and not my personal code.</s>

---

All of the answers here are great, and I've learned a lot from them.

Per @mesterlion comments, as of this time there is a single tool that does all of this, and does it correctly, properly maintained by the Pop!_OS team.

That tool is [`apt-manage`](https://repolib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/aptmanage/aptmanage.html) which is part of [**RepoLib**](https://repolib.readthedocs.io/) module which introduced the `key` sub-command in version 2.

So in Pop!_OS 22.04, installation will look like this:

```
sudo apt install --yes apt-manage
```

The upstream projects (Ubuntu and Debian) are missing this package, for that: the `apt-manage` project has a quick-install script (full disclosure, I submitted the PR for it).
Installing will look like:

```bash
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pop-os/repolib/HEAD/quick-install.sh | bash
```

More details can be found in the [Installation section](https://github.com/pop-os/repolib#installation) of the git-repo's `README.md`.

#### Example 1

After installing `apt-manage`, below is an example of a set of calls from my system:

```bash
# Adding PPA
sudo apt-manage add --terse --format=sources ppa:ppa:alessandro-strada/ppa

# Adding APT source and assinging a key
sudo apt-manage add --terse --format=sources --name Microsoft --identifier packages-microsoft-com 'deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/22.04/prod jammy main'
# Assigning a key via URL
sudo apt-manage key packages-microsoft-com --url=https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc

# R-Project needed some additional love - because they do something 'different':
sudo apt-manage add --terse --format=sources --name R-Project --identifier cloud-r-project-org 'deb [arch=amd64] https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu jammy-cran40/ ""_""'
# Specific to R-Project, as one of the values are empty and the command line can' pass it effectively.
sudo sed -i /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cloud-r-project-org.sources -Ee 's/""_""//g'
# Assigning a key via fingerprint
sudo apt-manage key cloud-r-project-org --fingerprint=E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9

# After all were added, run update.
sudo apt update
```

#### Example 2: Initialize docker on a fresh Ubuntu compute instance

```bash
set -e

export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

apt-get update \
&& apt-get install --yes --no-install-recommends \
    apt-transport-https ca-certificates \
    wget gnupg software-properties-common lsb-release \
    curl jq bash-completion

has() { command -v "$1" > /dev/null; }

# Try differnt ways of installing apt-manage
# First let's hope there is package ready for installation
has apt-manage \
|| curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pop-os/repolib/HEAD/quick-install.sh | bash 

# If the repo isn't part of existing apt sources, add it
REPO_URL="https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu"
APT_NAME="$(
    apt-manage list -a \
    | grep -B4 "${REPO_URL}" | head -1 \
    | sed -Ee 's/^\W*([^:]+):$/\1/'
)"
if [[ -n "${APT_NAME}" ]]; then
    >&2 printf '%s\n' \
        '' \
        "$(apt-manage list "${APT_NAME}")" \
        '' \
        "Docker repository found [${APT_NAME}]. Skipping."
else
    apt-manage add --identifier download-docker-com --name Docker \
        --terse --format=sources \
        "$( printf "deb [arch=%s] %s %s %s" \
            "$(dpkg --print-architecture)" \
            "${REPO_URL}" \
            "$(lsb_release --codename --short)" \
            "stable"
        )"

    apt-manage key download-docker-com \
        --url=https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg
fi
```

Comment: If you use PopOS, you can use `apt-manage` (from `repolib`) out-of-the-box

Comment: Didn't know about `apt-manage`. It look like the command only replaces the `sudo tee` line, which writes the `.list` file, but the `curl` to download the key and `gpg` still is needed. anyway, Another tool in the belt. Thanks @MestreLion!

Comment: `apt-manage` does have options to download the GPG key from an URL and associate it with a repository. By default it uses `/etc/apt/keyrings`, which Debian also recommends

Comment: @MestreLion, you are right, I edited my answer to reflect that, only to later discover this is currently available in Pop!_OS only.

Comment: It **is** available to Debian and Ubuntu, and works just fine in 22.04. Just get the `.deb` from their github release or create one yourself (instructions in their front page README): https://github.com/pop-os/repolib

Comment: Yet another way of installing on Ubuntu is to add the PopOS repository to `apt`: `add-apt-repository "deb https://apt.pop-os.org/release $(lsb_release -cs) main"`. That might be the best route (automatic updates), but ***make sure you also create an `apt` "pin" so it only pulls the `repolib` package from this repository and no other package!***. See https://wiki.debian.org/AptConfiguration#Prevent.2Fselective_installation_from_third-party_a_repository

Comment: I agree, but I think we leave it in the comments. I [remember](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/707773/138012) it's not hard, but also some non-trivial issues can bite you in the behind.

Comment: This looks interesting. I'll have to test this on a VM for myself, but looks promising at least..

Comment: Agree, don't really know why it doesn't get the love it deserves. It's a well written tool.

Comment: Updated with the official quick-install script.

Answer (score 0):

Keys for use by `apt` are stored in `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/`. `apt-key` managed these keyrings for you, but now that it's deprecated you need to choose a suitable file name `<KEYRING>` for the keyring yourself.

If you have the key already as a local file `<FILE>`, run

```
gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring=gnupg-ring:/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/<KEYRING>.gpg --import <FILE>
```

To directly read the key from `<URL>`, run

```
curl -sSfL <URL> | gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring=gnupg-ring:/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/<KEYRING>.gpg --import
```

Note: the prefix `gnupg-ring:` before the keyring name is required to create the keyring in the `apt` compatible (legacy) v4 format, rather than the (newer) keybox v1 format.

Comment: how should I modify the command you've mentioned, if I wanted to add `gpg key: EBB4CCF6A72BC110 | 55D9B3F8D3E163D4CED77D9CEBB4CCF6A72BC110` from this PPA: `https://launchpad.net/~ufleisch/+archive/ubuntu/kid3`. I tried: `curl -sSfL https://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?fingerprint=on&op=index&search=0x55D9B3F8D3E163D4CED77D9CEBB4CCF6A72BC110 | gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring=gnupg-ring:/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/<KEYRING>.gpg --import` but it didn't work.

Comment: (1) What should be the `<URL>` in case of this PPA: `https://launchpad.net/~ufleisch/+archive/ubuntu/kid3` ?

(2) Should I replace `<KEYRING>.gpg` with `gnupg-ring.gpg` ?  Thanks alot.

Comment: @Jags `curl -sSfL 'https://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0x55d9b3f8d3e163d4ced77d9cebb4ccf6a72bc110' | sudo gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring=gnupg-ring:/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/kid.gpg --import`

Comment: Thank you so much, and one more question please. When I wanna import multiple keys at once for a new installation, can I just add more URLs like `curl -sSfL <URL> <URL> <URL>` or no? Thank you.

Comment: The key was added just fine but now when I run `sudo apt update`, I'm getting alot of eerors like this: `W: http://ppa.launchpad.net/ufleisch/kid3/ubuntu/dists/hirsute/InRelease: The key(s) in the keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/kid.gpg are ignored as the file is not readable by user '_apt' executing apt-key.` Thanks alot.

Comment: @Jags `sudo chmod 0644 /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/kid.gpg`

Comment: @Jags "Can I just add more URLs?"

No. Also you probably want those in different keyrings anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the `*.asc` file you can just `--dearmor` it

```
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | gpg --dearmor > microsoft.gpg
install -o root -g root -m 644 microsoft.gpg /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/
```