# What repo do I need to add for Chrome updates?

Tags: 20.04, google-chrome

At some point during one update or another, whatever it was that made sure I got Chrome updates were disabled. What do I need to add in 20.04 to get Chrome updates again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup key with:

```
wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -
```

Setup repository with:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list'
```

Setup package with:

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt install google-chrome-stable
```

Comment: You should consider an alternate method of installing the PGP key instead of `apt-key add` - see [What commands should replace the deprecated apt-key?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1286545/what-commands-exactly-should-replace-the-deprecated-apt-key).