# How do I correctly setup a 3rd party repository with a 3rd party key without adding it to the global GPG keyring if I only have their keyid?

Tags: repository, gnupg, keyrings

I have a 3rd party software that is installed from their own repository and requires a custom key configured. Instead of adding their key to the global keyring, how do I correctly setup the key to be used only for that repository?

Typical error message would look like this:

> The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key
> is not available: NO_PUBKEY D208507CA14F4FCA

Comment: This was derived from https://askubuntu.com/a/1307181/451170 but I didn't have means to download the key directly, so had to figure out how to interact with the `keyserver` to get said key and deal with all the issues around `GPG`

Answer (score 0):

The `keyserver.ubuntu.com` can be used to retrieve the key, but you must manually confirm that the key is correct before proceeding:

[image]

```
sudo -H gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys D208507CA14F4FCA
```

This command puts the key in your global keyring, and is an intermediate step to export it. The key will be removed at a later step.

`-H` is needed to handle permissions issue regarding `sudo` and the HOME directory

Next is a sequence of commands to export the keyring

```
sudo -H gpg --export --output erlang.gpg D208507CA14F4FCA
mkdir -p /usr/local/share/keyrings
mv ./erlang.gpg /usr/local/share/keyrings/
```

And then remove the key from the keyring

```
sudo -H gpg --batch --yes --delete-key D208507CA14F4FCA
```

Create a subdirectory for `sources.list` and add the new config to it:

```
mkdir -p /etc/apt/sources.list.d
echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/local/share/keyrings/erlang.gpg] https://packages.erlang-solutions.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -s -c) contrib" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/erlang.list
```

Note that `add-apt-repository` [doesn't currently support the `[signed-by]` option](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-properties/+bug/1862764)

This process sets up the key for just that repository, limited the risk of a compromised 3rd party key from affecting unrelated repositories.

Comment: You can shorten the process to just three steps: Create directory for keyring: `sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/share/keyrings`, add keyring to directory: `sudo gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring /usr/local/share/keyrings/erlang.gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys D208507CA14F4FCA`, then add the repository to apt sources: `echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/local/share/keyrings/erlang.gpg] https://packages.erlang-solutions.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -s -c) contrib" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/erlang.list`