# What is the signed-by option in deb command?

Tags: apt, package-management, software-sources

I try to install `gcloud CLI` in my Linux and I am following the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install#deb) here.

From the installation part 1:

> Add the gcloud CLI distribution URI as a package source. If your
> distribution supports the signed-by option, run the following command:
>
> ```sh
>  echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg] https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list
> ```
>
> If your distribution doesn't support the signed-by option, run the
> following command:
>
> ```sh
> echo "deb https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list
> ```

I don't understand what the `signed-by` option means in the documentation and I cannot find any related information in `Ubuntu Documentation`.

Could you give me some advice/hints? Thanks.

**Note: I am using WSL2 with Ubuntu v20**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What commands (exactly) should replace the deprecated apt-key?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1286545/what-commands-exactly-should-replace-the-deprecated-apt-key)

Comment: It's a consequence of the fact that the command `apt-key` is deprecated (but still supported in Ubutnu 21.10, don't know what will happen in Ubuntu 22.04). See link above.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [`sources.list` manpage](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/sources.list.5) describes this option:

```
·  Signed-By (signed-by) is an option to require a repository to pass apt-secure(8)
   verification with a certain set of keys rather than all trusted keys apt has
   configured. It is specified as a list of absolute paths to keyring files (have to be
   accessible and readable for the _apt system user, so ensure everyone has
   read-permissions on the file) and fingerprints of keys to select from these keyrings. [...]
```

(There's much more detail in the full description.)

You can check in your particular version for this by looking for `signed-by` in `man 5 sources.list`. All current versions of Ubuntu support this option. It was added in apt 1.1, and Ubuntu 16.04 had 1.2.x, so anything newer than 16.04 will support it.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I want to know. I cannot find the documentation with the keywords `signed-by` and `ubuntu`.