# cannot update (Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring)

Tags: apt, updates

I cannot use update to my system due to keys problem

I tried to follow some answers to this problem but nothing works for me

```
$ sudo apt-get update                                                                                                            100 ⨯ 1 ⚙
Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ethereum/ethereum/ubuntu impish InRelease
Hit:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease                           
Hit:3 https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian bullseye InRelease                                             
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ethereum/ethereum/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                               
Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu impish InRelease                 
Hit:6 https://kali.itsec.am/kali kali-rolling InRelease                                          
Reading package lists... Done                  
W: http://ppa.launchpad.net/ethereum/ethereum/ubuntu/dists/impish/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
W: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
W: http://ppa.launchpad.net/ethereum/ethereum/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
W: http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu/dists/impish/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details
```

Comment: GPG keys have to be handled in a different way moving forward. Unfortunately, the system tools have not yet been updated (AFAIK). However, [I made a script](https://askubuntu.com/a/1321263/1066942) that makes installing new keys in the correct way as easy as possible.

Comment: @ArturMeinild i tried it but same problem :(

Comment: I see warnings, not errors. Are you sure that updates do not work?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?