# I was trying to download wine and this error occurred

Tags: apt, chromebook

*sudo apt-key add winehq.key*
**Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).**
OK

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu? Which release?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What commands (exactly) should replace the deprecated apt-key?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1286545/what-commands-exactly-should-replace-the-deprecated-apt-key)