# sudo apt-key add – does not work anymore

Tags: 22.04

I am trying to install (not by my choice) the Microsoft Windows Defender. For that i need to add a repository key:

```
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | sudo apt-key add –
```

But this does not work anymore.
I made then this to get the file:

```
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc -o /usr/local/share/keyrings/microsoft_windows_defender.key
```

I checked the file:

```
file usr/local/share/keyrings/microsoft_windows_defender.key
```

returns:

```
PGP public key block Public-Key (old)
```

then i created the source file

```
nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-prod.list
```

containing:

```
deb  [arch=amd64,armhf,arm64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/microsoft_windows_defender.gpg] https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/22.04/prod jammy main
```

But when i run

```
apt update
```

It gives an error:

```
 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/22.04/prod jammy InRelease: NO_PUBKEY EB3E94ADBE1229CF
```

Can anyone help to fix this?
Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What commands (exactly) should replace the deprecated apt-key?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1286545/what-commands-exactly-should-replace-the-deprecated-apt-key)

Comment: gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://itsfoss.com/apt-key-deprecated/

1. The keys have to be dearmored and added in binary format.
   `$ curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | gpg --dearmor | sudo tee /usr/share/keyrings/microsoft_windows_defender.gpg`
2. `$ echo " deb  [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/microsoft_windows_defender.gpg arch=amd64,armhf,arm64] https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/22.04/prod jammy main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-prod.list`
3. `$ sudo apt update`