# Pgadmin 4 installation on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: apt, 22.04, pgadmin

Looking to install pgadmin4 to ubuntu 22.04.

I used the following:

```
curl https://www.pgadmin.org/static/packages_pgadmin_org.pub | sudo apt-key add
Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).
```

I then found a tutorial That suggested using:

```
wget -0- https://example.com/key/repo-key.gpg> | gpg--dearmor | sudo tee /usr/share/keyrings/<myrepository>-archive-keyring.gpg
```

I'm just not quite sure how to use the command (or if its even what will address the issue).

Postgresql is installed.

Note: apologies in advance - I'm brand new to linux and command line so I'm not super familiar with the fundamentals yet.

Comment: In this perspective your question is brief and more details should be added to your question like these points: - What tutorial have you followed to install `PgAdmin4`? - What commands did you use to install `PgAdmin4`? - Is `postgresql` installed on your Ubuntu? I'd suggest you to use the [official website](https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgadmin-4-apt/) for downloading and installing `PgAdmin4` but without more details I seem to not have an actual idea of how you are trying to install it.

Comment: I added some additional details for clarity. I did use the official site under "apt", but their commands didn't work for me as it seems part of the command isn't available in ubuntu (apt-key).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What commands (exactly) should replace the deprecated apt-key?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1286545/what-commands-exactly-should-replace-the-deprecated-apt-key)