# Install MongoDB using shell script

Tags: bash, mongodb

I'm trying to use a shell script to automate the task of setting up MongoDB on Ubuntu 20.04 as follows:

**mongodb_install.sh***

```bash
MONGO_VERSION=6.0

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gnupg

# import MongoDB GPG public key
wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-${MONGO_VERSION}.asc | sudo apt-key add -
sudo cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
sudo touch mongodb-org-${MONGO_VERSION}.list
echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/${MONGO_VERSION} multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-${MONGO_VERSION}.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org

sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb
sudo chown mongodb:mongodb /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
sudo service mongod start
sudo systemctl status mongod
```

After running the script I receive status 'active':

```
● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2022-11-03 14:04:45 +07; 7ms ago
       Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
   Main PID: 74147 (mongod)
     Memory: 796.0K
     CGroup: /system.slice/mongod.service
             └─74147 /usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf
```

Yet when I recheck in the terminal mongod service does not start:

```
$ systemctl status mongod
mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2022-11-03 14:04:45 +07; 7s ago
       Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
    Process: 74147 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=exited, status=14)
   Main PID: 74147 (code=exited, status=14)
```

I have tried different combinations of `sudo ./mongodb_install.sh`, `sudo . ./mongodb_install.sh`, etc., but nothing has worked so far.

Could you show me a way to resolve this?

Comment: Could you include more of the `systemctl status mongod` output, including the log entries? There must be some logs showing errors.

Comment: Using `apt-key add` is a really bad idea - [see here why](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1286545/what-commands-exactly-should-replace-the-deprecated-apt-key). You should instead install the key to `/etc/apt/keyrings`.

Comment: @ArturMeinild that's interesting, this is the instruction I get from MongoDB official site

Comment: Yes, and that instruction is clearly outdated. See my revised answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use of `apt-key add` is [heavily not recommended](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1286545/what-commands-exactly-should-replace-the-deprecated-apt-key), and not even possible on Ubuntu 22.04 and later. Instead, install the key to `/etc/apt/keyrings` and refer to this key in the `.list` file:

So your script would look like:

```
MONGO_VERSION=6.0
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gnupg -y
# Changes here!
  sudo mkdir -p /etc/apt/keyrings
  curl -fsSL https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-${MONGO_VERSION}.asc | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/keyrings/mongodb-${MONGO_VERSION}.gpg
cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
sudo touch mongodb-org-${MONGO_VERSION}.list
# And here!
  echo "deb [arch=amd64,arm64 signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/mongodb-${MONGO_VERSION}.gpg] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/${MONGO_VERSION} multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-${MONGO_VERSION}.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
sudo systemctl start mongod
```

And yes, somebody who uses MongoDB should probably tell them that [their guide is outdated](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/) in this aspect.

Answer (score 0):

I made 2 changes in order for this to work:

1. Add **-y flag** when installing gnupg: `sudo apt-get install gnupg -y`
2. Remove the `chown` section:

```
sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb
sudo chown mongodb:mongodb /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
sudo service mongod start
sudo systemctl status mongod
```

The resulting shell script for installing MongoDB 6.0 on Ubuntu 20.04 is as follows:

```
MONGO_VERSION=6.0
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gnupg -y
wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-${MONGO_VERSION}.asc | sudo apt-key add -
cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
sudo touch mongodb-org-${MONGO_VERSION}.list
echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/${MONGO_VERSION} multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-${MONGO_VERSION}.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
sudo systemctl start mongod
```