# Ubuntu 22.10 : Fix missing GPG Key

Tags: apt, xubuntu, ppa, gnupg

On ubuntu 22.10, I am facing this error of missing public key, went through a lot of articles and tried doing everything but still the error remains the same.

1. Using this command,  `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 4EB27DB2A3B88B8B` and `gpg --export --armor 4EB27DB2A3B88B8B | sudo apt-key add -` and at last `sudo apt-get update`. But still, same error of not able to find any public image.

   [image]
2. I tried adding **keyserver in the gpg.conf** file but still the error persists.
3. I tried copying the public key from the ubuntu keyserver, pasting it into a file and then running `sudo apt-key add key1` command but no luck, still the same error.

Please suggest a way to get rid of this error.

Comment: Please search the site, or ask a new question about `y-ppa-manager` - this has nothing to do with the missing Google key.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Google's PGP key for the repository in the correct way - [also see here](https://www.google.com/linuxrepositories/) (which indicates the old and *incorrect* way of doing it).

First download the key and install it: *(Notice that `sudo apt-key add -` has been replaced with `sudo gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/keyrings/google_key.gpg`, which is the preferred way to do this)*

```
wget -q -O - https://dl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/keyrings/google_key.gpg
```

Now edit your Google repository file to reference the keyring:

```
nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/chrome.list
```

Edit the contents of the file to this: *(Here I'm assuming your architecture is `amd64`)*

```
deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/google_key.gpg] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
```

Now running `sudo apt update` should work again.

Please also [read this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1286545/what-commands-exactly-should-replace-the-deprecated-apt-key/), about general information for future APT key management.