# google chrome deprecated key on ubuntu

Tags: apt, software-installation, 22.04, google-chrome

I was installing google chrome browser on my Ubuntu 22.04 through Google's repository. When I add the GPG key, it throws a warning stating, "warning: apt-key is deprecated"

the command I used to add the key is.

```
wget -q -O - https://dl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -
```

although the installation followed by this step was successful, but I am curious about this warning and how to get rid of this.

Comment: It's just a warning, no need to worry (for now).

Comment: Also see [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1286545/what-commands-exactly-should-replace-the-deprecated-apt-key)..

Answer (score 0):

Use this command to install the keys, you also need to remove old ones

```
wget -q -O - https://dl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | gpg --dearmor | sudo tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/chrome.gpg
```