# I need only to purge apt packages, but no names and after purge remains there

Tags: apt, package-management

After `sudo apt update` detected bugs, so, I want to PURGE the packages... But what the package name?  how to purge it?

I try remove the listed bugs (final below), but:

- `sudo apt purge pgadmin4`, no effect. "Package 'pgadmin4' is not installed, so not removed"
- `sudo apt purge qgis`,  ok! Purge, no QGIS on machine, but the warning alert remains.

The `apt` show warnings,  but not show *package names*, so it is difficult to discover what I must to purge. **How to really purge?**

---

The bugs listed by `apt update`, that remains the same after qgis purge:

```
W: https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/apt/jammy/dists/pgadmin4/
InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), 
see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
W: https://qgis.org/ubuntu/dists/jammy/
InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), 
see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'https://qgis.org/ubuntu jammy 
InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
```

Comment: There are two things going on here - `apt-key` deprecation (the GPG signing keys for those repositories are still in the system even thoug the packages arent!), and the repository is still added for qgis and does NOT have i386 packages available, hence the N-level error

Answer (score 1):

Those are not package errors. Adding or removing the packages will have no effect (as you have discovered).

Those are repository (W)arnings and (N)otifications. You must fix (or disable or remove) the repository listing among your apt sources.

Example: The https://qgis.org apt source must be fixed, disabled, or removed to eliminate the W: warning. It's usually in your `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` directory.

- You can FIX the problem using the instructions in [What commands (exactly) should replace the deprecated apt-key?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1286545/what-commands-exactly-should-replace-the-deprecated-apt-key)
- You can DISABLE the source using your Software & Settings control panel, or by going into the source file (usually in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`) and commenting out the source. Then run `sudo apt update` because your sources just changed.
- You can DELETE the source by deleting the source file (usually in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`), or deleting the lines from within the sources file. Then run `sudo apt update` because your sources just changed.
- You can DELETE the "apt key" by deleting the source file (usually in `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d`), avoiding recent UBUNTU errors/warnings about `apt-key` deprecation. Then run `sudo apt update` because your sources just changed.

Comment: "repository listing ... apt sources"?  No at `/etc/apt/sources.list`.  Can I remove similar file names from `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`?  for example `pgadmin4.list` and `archive_uri-https_qgis_org_ubuntu-jammy.list`

Comment: Edited to answer your comment.

Comment: Thanks!  Plus one procedure: I removed the similar files of directory `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d`... This corrected the "apt-key error".