# Warning: apt-key is deprecated, when installing Microsoft Edge

Tags: command-line, browser, wget, curl, tee

To [install](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/745298/101935) Microsoft Edge, the suggestion is to:

```
wget -q https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
```

however, this is now deprecated.  So the suggestion is to now use something like:

```
curl -sS https://download.spotify.com/debian/pubkey_5E3C45D7B312C643.gpg | gpg --dearmor | sudo tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/spotify.gpg
```

However, I'm not quite clear on how to adapt that `curl` command to fit the Microsoft link above.  When using `tee`, this is added to an existing Microsoft `.gpg` file, or am I creating it?

Context appreciated to better understand.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What commands (exactly) should replace the deprecated apt-key?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1286545/what-commands-exactly-should-replace-the-deprecated-apt-key)

Comment: still trying to figure it out @ArturMeinild

Comment: There are updated instructions here: https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2021/01/how-to-install-edge-on-ubuntu-linux