# Couldn't load your calendar. Let's give it another try -- Microsoft Teams error

Tags: software-installation, browser, calendar, google-calendar, microsoft-teams

Having just [installed](https://askubuntu.com/q/1467125/847449) Microsoft Edge, am looking for a calendar, but get:

[image: no calendar]

This is after having [removed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/745298/101935) the official snap app.

Bit flummoxed as to how to determine the cause of this error.

Comment: Apologies, but I’m not quite certain what the question is (aside from “how do I fix this?” … but I don’t know what “this” is). Could you [edit] your question to include: (0) the version of Ubuntu you’re using (1) whether this error is in Edge or a different application (2) which calendar you’re trying to load (Teams view, Outlook, something else) (3) anything else that might help specify the issue. With this, it may be possible to offer a solution 

Comment: I'll update the q, but quick reply:  any calendar would be an achievement at this point, it's 22.04 and, correct, there's not any diagnostic information which comes to mind.