# I get a lot of errors and warnings while trying sudo apt update

Tags: repository, keyrings

I am quite new to Linux desktop and I've encountered some problems with repositories. Whenever I try to update I get a bunch of errors related to public keys in repositories. I've seen there are similar questions related to this, but none of them quite fixes my problem. `

```
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/papirus/papirus/ubuntu lunar InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY E58A9D36647CAE7F
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/kubuntu-ppa/backports/ubuntu lunar InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 2836CB0A8AC93F7A
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu lunar Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

The way I managed this is by following the "the quick way" on this site https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2022/06/fix-apt-key-deprecation-error-on-ubuntu

Comment: This is a common question. Does this answer it? [What commands (exactly) should replace the deprecated apt-key?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1286545/what-commands-exactly-should-replace-the-deprecated-apt-key)

Comment: Don't add abandoned PPAs. [What can I do if a repository/PPA does not have a Release file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/what-can-i-do-if-a-repository-ppa-does-not-have-a-release-file)

Comment: A quick look from what you provided in your paste & I see a PPA that last maintained in 2019; yet you expected support for a release from 2023?  Did you look at https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/y-ppa-manager  (note:  that was obtained from your provided detail!) as PPAs are 3rd party sources where all security checks are on you to perform.  Is your intended purpose to explore what happens when you add *unmaintained* software to your system & researching malware etc?

Comment: You should always provide your OS/release in your question; it makes it easier for us trying to help you. I mentioned 2023 as your paste mentions *lunar* or Ubuntu 23.04; ie. the 2023-April release.. the link I copy/paste to obtain https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/y-ppa-manager from your link shows that supports Ubuntu products up to 19.10 (2019-October release), ie. not 22.04 LTS or later, so your error was adding a PPA that doesn't support your release (*maybe failing to do required security checks to protect your system, or not doing them properly*)

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/what-can-i-do-if-a-repository-ppa-does-not-have-a-release-file. This helped with the warnings, the error I solved by just removing the faulty repository. I know it may not be the best approach and maybe it even hinders the process of learning Linux, but I've also used ChatGPT to solve the problem. It is not the best method to do something, but if you want your problem solved quickly, it might help. Thank you all for the answers