# Notice apt-key deprecation warning when updating system Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: apt, updates, 22.04, keyrings

Recently I've noticed some issues when running apt where the system will warn me of a keyring deprecation:

> All packages are up to date.
> W: https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/22.04/prod/dists/jammy/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.

This doesn't stop me from performing the update, but I would much rather not see this when updating my system. How are we supposed to store trusted GPG keys going forward?

Comment: Read `man apt-key`. Reread the "`DEPRECATION`" section.

Comment: Duplicate of  [What commands (exactly) should replace the deprecated apt-key?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1286545/what-commands-exactly-should-replace-the-deprecated-apt-key)