# I added a GPG key but it is not appearing in the key list

Tags: apt, software-installation, 22.04, gnupg, mongodb

I added a new GPG key using this command:

```
curl -fsSL https://pgp.mongodb.com/server-7.0.asc | \
   sudo gpg -o /usr/share/keyrings/mongodb-server-7.0.gpg \
   --dearmor
```

The file is appearing in `/usr/share/keyrings/mongodb-server-7.0.gpg` but when I run `sudo apt-key list`, there is no entry for it, and it is giving an error while running `apt update`. How do I fix this?

Comment: Since you have already downloaded the key, you need to follow the part starting from "At this point, nothing has changed and apt doesn't know the key exists" in https://askubuntu.com/a/1307181/158442

Comment: @muru, thanks that worked. Although my key is in `/usr/share/keyrings/` and not `/etc/apt/keyrings/`. Will this not be a problem?

Comment: It's not likely, but packages can install files in `/usr/share`, so your keyring might conflict if some package somehow adds a file with the exact same path, but again, not likely to happen.